# JQuery or Javascript that will make an element fade away automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I am making a clicker game and am kind of stuck. I want a popup like cookieClicker has when you get an achievement. It pops up and tells you what happened, you can click the x or it will just fade away after a few seconds.

I tried making something with pure javascript and CSS to no avail, it would fade away nicely but not automatically.

So how do I make it so whenever X element is made/displayed then it goes away after 3 seconds?

Also, if it matters the element would be created by a javascript function, and multiples might be created at the same time.

P.S. I tried searching and found something about auto-fading in javascript but nothing in there seemed to work either.

EDIT: After trying to view cookieclicker source and playing the game again it appears it doesn't even have this functionality. The closest thing I can compare it to is when you would add something to your cart on a website, then it alerts you the item was added and then fades away.

Comment: Hi. If you edit this question to  show us what you tried, we can tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: I wish I still had it, but I deleted that code a few hours ago when it failed. I am just now posting.

Comment: Have you tried this: `setTimeout(function () { $("#YourModal_Id").modal("hide"); }, 2000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your openPopup function might look like this:

`function openPopup(/* options here */) {
    const popup = actuallyOpenPopup();
    waitSomeTimeAndCloseIfNotClosedYet(popup);
}`

where 2nd function should take a popup instance (which has .close method probably, or dismiss)
and start a timeout. You need to keep that timeout, so if close was called, you need to cancel it.

Something like this:

```
function waitSomeTimeAndCloseIfNotClosedYet(popup) {
    const originalClose = popup.close;

    /* monkey patching, decorating, 
       separate method - whatever you prefer */
    popup.close = function () {
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        originalClose.call(this);
    };

    popup.timeout = setTimeout(() => popup.close(), 3000);
}
```

So, if was closed manually - it wont be called twice, if not, will fire up a timeout and close automatically.

Via CSS you can only achieve visible closing, but not removal of nodes. (Google for transition visibility, fade out modal etc.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: But how do I open up the popup without using an existing Javascript function? I'm kind of new to Javascript and this is the last part of this project I have left to do and am just having the hardest time for some reason :/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach which uses Javascript to trigger a CSS transition:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

function autoFader() {

if (window.getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue('display') === 'none') {

    div.style.display = 'block';

        setTimeout(function(){
            div.style.opacity = '0';
        },10);

        setTimeout(function(){
            div.removeAttribute('style');
        },4010);

    }
}

button.addEventListener('click',autoFader,false);
```

```css
div {
display: none;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 6px;
font-size: 20px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
text-align: center;
border: 3px solid rgb(127,0,0);
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity 3s linear 1s;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click Me</button>

<div>
<p>Hi, I'm an auto-fading pop-up.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm going to try adapting it to call the popup from within other functions. Mess with the timing etc...